# T is a nonempty subset of S. (a) Show that T is bounded (b) Show that glb S $\leq$ glb T $\leq$ lub T $ \leq$ lubS

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose that S is a nonempty bounded set of real numbers and T is a nonempty subset of S.

(a) Show that T is bounded:

(b) Show that glb S $\leq$ glb T $\leq$ lub T $ \leq$ lubS

---

for (a) it seems intuitive that T is bounded because it exists in the bounded set S. But explaining this with some rigor is tough...

for (b) it seems also intuitive that since T is a subset of S it by necessity will have an equal or greater glb and an equal or lesser lub than S... but I'm struggling to explain it definitively... any thoughts?

Comment: What does it mean for $S$ to be bounded?

Comment: That the set is of a finite size?

Comment: What do you mean by that? "Size" is not a common mathematical term. Look up the definition of "bounded set" in your math book (or anywhere else) before you start working on this exercise.